# Extract previous value by group from other group column

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame:

```
ID_1  <- c("A","B","C","D","A","A","B","E","D","F","H")
ID_2  <- c("G","D","I","A","J","B","K","D","A","H","A")
Value <- c(10,9,15,27,3,28,4,3,11,19,12)
DF <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID_1, ID_2, Value))
```

I would like to have a new column, which includes the last (i.e., preceeding) value ('Value') for a given ID ('ID_1') based on the corresponding ID in another column ('ID_2'). In other words: The intended solution should find the most recent/last ID entry ('ID_2') for given ID ('ID_1') and extract the corresponding value ('Value') in a new column.

The final data set should look like this (one new column is added to the existing three columns; illustration):

```
NEW    <- c(NA,NA,NA,9,27,27,28,NA,3,NA,19)
DF_NEW <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID_1, ID_2, Value, NEW))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to create a row number column on DF, then use `data.table` rolling join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, rn := seq_len(.N)]

DF[DF, 
    on=.(ID_2 = ID_1, rn = rn), 
    .(ID_1 = i.ID_1, ID_2 = i.ID_2, Value = i.Value, New = x.Value), 
    roll=Inf
]

#    ID_1 ID_2 Value New
# 1:    A    G    10  NA
# 2:    B    D     9  NA
# 3:    C    I    15  NA
# 4:    D    A    27   9
# 5:    A    J     3  27
# 6:    A    B    28  27
# 7:    B    K     4  28
# 8:    E    D     3  NA
# 9:    D    A    11   3
#10:    F    H    19  NA
#11:    H    A    12  19
```

Comment: Cool :) Works! Thank you, Psidom!